# Condinonal Probability on weather it rains given he brings umbrella.

Tags: probability

`In London, half of the days have some rain. The weather forecaster is correct 2/3 of the time, i.e., the probability that it rains, given that she has predicted rain, and the probability that it does not rain, given that she has predicted it won't rain, are both equal to 2/3. When rain is forecast, Mr. Pickwick takes his umbrella. When rain is not forecast, he takes it with probability 1/3.`

> 1. Find the probability that it doesn't rain, given that he brings his umbrella.

```
`P(PW ^ R~ ) = 1/2(1)1/3+1/2(1/3)2/3  = 5/18
P(R~ |PW)  =  P(PW ^ R~ ) / P(PW) = 5/18 /  (5/6)  = 1/3`
```

P(PW) PickWick brings the umbrella 
P(R~) doesn't rain

I am not sure how to calculate the denominator I Used 1(1/2) + 1/2(2/3) = 5/6 . 
Could you please help in understanding the denominator part in detail if its wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following probability Model -

A - {It rains}

B - {Forecaster says it rains}

C - {Mr. Pickwick carries umbrella}

Now it is given - $$P(A) = 1/2; P(A\mid B) = 2/3; P(A'\mid B') = 2/3; P(C\mid B) = 1; P(C'\mid B) = 1/3$$
Now $P(A'\mid B') = (1-P(A \cup B))/P(B') = 2/3$
$$\Rightarrow P(A\cup B) = 1/3+2/3P(B)$$

Also from $P(A\mid B)$ we get $P(A\cap B) = 2/3P(B)$

So from here we can calculate $P(B) = 1/2$ and using this and $P(C\mid B), P(C'\mid B)$ we have
$$P(C) = 2/3$$

[image: Probability Model]

Using the probability tree (event $C \cap A^{'}$ has branches $2$ and $3$):

$$P(C \cap A^{'}) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 \cdot\frac{1}{3} \;+\; \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3} = \frac{5}{18}.$$

$$\therefore P(A^{'}\mid C) = \dfrac{P(A^{'}\cap C)}{P(C)} = \frac{5/18}{2/3} = \frac{5}{12}.$$